# Can RocksDB handle multiple read-only clients?

Tags: python, key-value, leveldb, kyotocabinet, rocksdb

I need a key-value database, like redis or memcached, but not in memory and rather on disk. After filling the database (which we do regularly and from scratch), I'd actually only need the `get` operation, but from many different processes (so Kyoto Cabinet and LevelDB do not work for me).

I need like 5 million keys and `~10-30gb` of data, so some other simple databases don't work as well.

I can't find any information on whether [RocksDB](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb) can handle multiple read-only clients; it's not straight-forward to build on my OS so I wanted to ask before doing that. If it can't, is there any database which would work? Preferably with an Ubuntu package and Python bindings ;-).

We're just using many-many small files now, but it really sucks, as we want easy backups, copying, etc. I also suspect this may cause slowdowns, but it doesn't really matter that much.

Comment: Have you considered SQLite?

Comment: Actually, nope. Is it really good for such a use-case?

Comment: Yes, just create a single table with key/value columns. You would use normal SQL to access the table. Not sure keys can be purely binary though. With the advent of WAL (Write-ahead-logging), you can even support writing in parallel with multiple readers. SQLite only supports a single concurrent writer though. Also note that though you say "processes", if you mean different computers, then I would disregard SQLite. SQLite is good for local databases, but not so good for networked databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is probably Berkeley DB, and bindings are a part of the stdlib: https://docs.python.org/2/library/anydbm.html

Comment: thanks, I'll try that! for some reason it says it's deprecated, and that I should use pybsddb: http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb_doc/contents.html

Comment: Berkeley DB performs horribly compared to all recent key-val DBs in every benchmarks I found.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you should be able to run multiple read-only clients on a single RocksDB database. Just open the database with DB::OpenForReadOnly() call: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/master/include/rocksdb/db.h#L108